# Как с помощью radio inputa сделать динамическое изменение цены опционального товара?

Tags: jquery, radio

Здравствуйте! 
Делаю сайт, заказ Суши и роллы и там есть опциональные товары (например Роллы), прежде чем добавить в корзину клиенту нужно выбрать кол-во, т.е 4 шт. или 8 шт. и соответственно стоимость товара должна меняться при выборе. 
Обычно это делается select' ом но select' ы не всегда смотрится красиво, поэтому сделал radio input' ом (+label) и не знаю как это сделать.

Вот так выглядеть сайт:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
и видео https://youtu.be/r_domj9Roqg

Вот HTML код

```html
<div class="product-item">
    <div class="caption">
      <h5><a href="#">Ролл с лососем</a></h5>
      <div class="variations">
        <input type="radio" id="variat-1" name="Количества" value="4 шт." data-price="100" checked>
        <label for="variat-1">4 шт.</label>
        <input type="radio" id="variat-2" name="Количества" value="8 шт." data-price="189">
        <label for="variat-2">8 шт.</label>
      </div>
      <p class="price">100</p>
      <a href="#">В корзину</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Как можно это реализовать? Вообще можно ли сделать с помощью radio?

Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дописал скрипт (разметка та же):

```js
$(document).on("change", ".variations input", function () {
  var $target = $(event.target)
  $target.closest(".caption").find(".price").text($target.data("price"))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="product-item">
    <div class="caption">
      <h5><a href="#">Ролл с лососем</a></h5>
      <div class="variations">
        <input type="radio" id="variat-1" name="Количества" value="4 шт." data-price="100" checked>
        <label for="variat-1">4 шт.</label>
        <input type="radio" id="variat-2" name="Количества" value="8 шт." data-price="189">
        <label for="variat-2">8 шт.</label>
      </div>
      <p class="price">100</p>
      <a href="#">В корзину</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю, очень помог! То что надо!

Answer (score 1):

Обычно это делается так: располагаются radio и скрываются (через `display:none`). А, например внутри `label` располагается какой-либо тег, который оформляется кастомным образом.

Пример:

```css
div {
  margin:0 0 0.75em 0;
}

input[type="radio"] {
    display:none;
}
input[type="radio"] + label {
    color: $DarkBrown;
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
}
input[type="radio"] + label span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:19px;
    height:19px;
    margin:-1px 4px 0 0;
    vertical-align:middle;
    cursor:pointer;
    -moz-border-radius:  50%;
    border-radius:  50%;
}

input[type="radio"] + label span {
     background-color:#292321;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label span{
     background-color:#CC3300;
}

input[type="radio"] + label span,
input[type="radio"]:checked + label span {
  -webkit-transition:background-color 0.4s linear;
  -o-transition:background-color 0.4s linear;
  -moz-transition:background-color 0.4s linear;
  transition:background-color 0.4s linear;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="radio01" name="radio" />
  <label for="radio01"><span></span>Radio Button 1</label>
</div>

<br/>

<div>
 <input type="radio" id="radio02" name="radio" />
 <label for="radio02"><span></span>Radio Button 2</label>
</div>
```

В данном случае идет оформление тега `<span>` внутри `label`.

Если закоментируете строки:

```
input[type="radio"] {
    display:none;
}
```

то увидите, что атрибут `checked` у кнопки благополучно проставляется

Comment: Мне кажется, или ты вообще не на тот вопрос отвечаешь? Я понял, что у него всё кроме изменения стоимости готово.

Comment: @Qwertiy может быть)

Comment: Спасибо, этот вариант тоже подходить!